# How can I debug openURL from a pass of Wallet on iOS ?

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

I created a pass with appLaunchURL and associatedStoreIdentifiers, and added to Wallet.

I built and installed my app with Xcode on iPhone, I'd like to check if on the backside of the pass, when I click the link open, my app is able to navigate to some page in my app.
But Wallet seems not able to detect my installed app but instead, link me to AppStore to download the AppStore version.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can set option in target autolaunch for this

Comment: @sage444 you mean in Xcode Scheme-->Run-->Info tab-->Option Launch automatically ? It's already set.

Comment: Yes, is exactly what I mean

Comment: I don't see how it can help. My problem is that Wallet cannot detect my installed app.

Comment: @BinChen Hi, have you ever find the solution or root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Normally if there is an app in your device, it will show [open] button to open your application. So you have to make sure that your application in your device is correctly download from app store.